# Django: Setting def __str__ to a Related Model

Tags: django, django-models, django-related-manager

Objective: I am trying to set the `__str__` of a model to the name of a related model. The `Profile` model has a `__str__` that returns "last name, first name" of the user. I would like the `Inspector` to return something similar with their `inspector_number`.

Currently: The `__str__` is returning "users.Profile.None 12345" instead of the **desired "Doe, John 12345".**

This is one of my first times using `related_name` for a model and I seem to be missing something.

Model.py

```
class Profile(BaseModel):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    inspector = models.ForeignKey(Inspector, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name="inspector_profile")
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.last_name + ", " + self.user.first_name



class Inspector(BaseModel):

...

    inspector_number = models.CharField(max_length=19, unique=True, editable=False, default=get_inspector_number)


    def __str__(self):
        ret = str(self.inspector_profile) + " " + str(self.inspector_number)
        return ret
```

*Update:*
I was able to solve the issue by using `if hasattr(self, 'inspector_profile'):`. All of the records had the attribute but this seemed to correct my issue.

Comment: It looks like there is no Profile related to your Inspector instance. Are you sure the data is correct? You should probably check if the inspector has this relation since it is nullable

Comment: @vinkomlacic Agreed, that is exactly what it looks like but if I go into the Profile then I can see the Inspector is assigned. If I remove the Inspector from the Profile then it still shows the same information/result.

Comment: I guess it's something related to model design. You could make the `__str__` of the Profile to print the desired string. For example, `return self.user.last_name + ", " + self.user.first_name + inspector.inspector_number`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this happens is because `inspector` is a `ForeignKey`. This means that an `Inspector` can have zero, one, or more related `Profile`s, and this also means that `self.inspector_profile` is not a `Profile` object, but a `RelatedObjectManager` that manages `Profile` objects. You can for example print all the related `Profile` names with:

```
class Inspector(BaseModel):
    # …
    
    def __str__(self):
        profiles = [str(profile) for profile in self.inspector_profile.all()]
        return f'{" ".join(profiles)} {self.inspector_number}'
```

But probably the main question is if an `Inspector` should be related to potentially *multiple* `Profile`s, and that the relation should not be a `OneToOneField` from `Inspector` to `Profile`.